# Neo4j-shell is not starting up

Tags: java, neo4j, jvm-arguments

I have a problem using neo4j-shell in my mac.
When I tried to start it up, these information showed up.

[image]

But I have Xms and Xmx set to 128 and 512 respectively and I did that in .bash_profile file

[image]

How can I fix this problem? Thx!

Comment: You forgot the `m` with `-Xmx512m`

Comment: @MichaelHunger I add the m making the -Xmx512m, but it does not work. I still can not start up the neo4j-shell. I think I may put those variables in the wrong place. Is that right to put them in the .bash_profile file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting caught by a typo.  Instead of `-Xmx512` it should be `-Xmx512m`.

You're specifying that the initial size should be 128MB, and that the maximum size should be 512 bytes.  Without the `m`, that doesn't make sense.  :)

**EDIT** - I tried your sample, and upped `-XX:MaxPermSize` to 512m, and it works for me:

`export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"`

Comment: I still can not start it up after I added the missing m. Do you think I put those variables in the wrong place?

Comment: Updated answer - try tweaking -XX:MaxPermSize